# Reason for assertEquals() failing

Tags: java, junit

The assertEquals() fails even though the both the strings are same...can someone help me figure out why?

```
 public void testSet() 
 {
    ByteArrayOutputStream outContent = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    System.setOut(new PrintStream(outContent));

    instance.get();

    String output = outContent.toString();
    String input="i=1\r\n";
    assertEquals(input,output);
 }

 get()
 {
    int i=1;
    System.out.println("i="+i);
 }
```

Comment: `println` adds an `'\n'`, methinks. Check `output.length()`.

Comment: @DanielFischer I tried adding '\n' to input still assertEquals() fails..also now input.length()=4 and output.length=5...but i m not getting the reason as to why it is happening

Comment: Are you on Windows? Then you'd probably need `"\r\n"`. Or, better use `print` instead of `println`, then it should work independent of platform.

Comment: @DanielFischer ya am on windows and i want to make it platform independent...also i do want to use println...is there some way out

Comment: How about [trim](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim())?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `newline` in your print statement in your `get()` method which is appending `\r\n` in the output buffer. This way you are getting `output  = "i=1\r\n" which is not equal to "i=1".

Use the `print without newline i.e. print()` as below:

```
 System.out.print("i="+i);
```

If you don't want to use `print()` method then truncate the `\r\n` from the output as below:

```
    String output = outContent.toString();
    output = output.replaceAll("\r\n", "");
    String input="i=1";
    assertEquals(input,output);
```

Comment: but i want to use System.out.println() is there some way i can get through

Comment: @user1778824: Yes, truncate it. Added a sample code in the answer.

Comment: @user1778824 So either remove the newline from the string before you test it, or include the newline sequence in the test. You can get the platform newline sequence from java.lang.System.